# Changing ExtJS microloader script mime type

Tags: javascript, extjs

When `ExtJS` is in production mode, by default it generates the following `<script>` element for the application bundle / `Bootstrap Microloader` in my `index.jsp`.

`<script type="text/javascript"> //content </script>`

Additionally, in the microloader code I have the following code segment generated.

`c.type="text/javascript"`

Is there some setting I can use in order to for the microloader to use
`application/x-javascript` instead of `text/javascript`?: